# Ansible: How to check if dictionary has at least one specified value?

Tags: ansible

Say I need to execute an Ansible task only when some dictionary contains at least one `false` value?

EXAMPLE:

```yaml
vars:
  dict_fonts_installed: { font1: true, font2: true, font3: false }
  
tasks:
  - name: 'Run fc-cache only if at least one of the fonts isn't installed'
    command: "fc-cache -f {{ fonts_dir }}"
    when: <YOUR ANSWER>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you are looking for is:

```yaml
when: false in dict_fonts_installed.values()
```